# recoll results paragraph width is variable

Tags: css, customization, recoll

As seen in the attached, some results paragraphs do not "conform" to what seems to be the "standard" specification for width (visible from results paragraph at top of image.

[image]

How can we control (limit) the overall width of the table to prevent the oversize table that was generated for "productdata.js" ?

Also, the left-side box with icon and "fit" factor is specified in the header with width = 100px, but the oversize table/paragraph seems to have overriden this and reduced the width to the width of the icon plus margin.  Is there any way to prevent that from happening ?

The current contents of the **paragraph CSS** is:

```
<table style="background-color: #AFAFAF; width: 850px;"
<!--    <table class="parspec" style="background-color: #AFAFAF;"   -->
    border-style="none" border-color:="" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;
        background-color: #0F0F0F;"
        rowspan="4" >
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img src="%I" width="64px" height="auto">   <!-- set width of thumbnail -->
            <span>
                <img src="%U">
            </span>
            </a>
            <p style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #4F9F4F;"><b>%R</b></p>
        </td>

    <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
        <th
            style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #DFDFDF;
            background-color: #000000; text-align: left;"
            colspan="3" >
            %T</th>
        </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; "></td>

    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center;
        background-color: #000000; color: #CFCF4F;">
        <b><font size=2>%M</font></b></td>

    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center;
        background-color: #000000; color: #CFCF4F;">
        <b><font size=2>%D</font></b></td>

    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: right;
        background-color: #000000; color: #CFCF4F;">
        <b><font size=2>%S</font></b></td>
    </tr>

<tr style="font-family: sans-serif;" 8="">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; "></td>

    <td class="snippet" colspan="3">
        %A</td>
    </tr>

<tr style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #9F;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; "></td>

    <td style="background-color: #000000; color: #BFBFEF;"
        colspan="3">
        <b><font size=2>%U</font></b><br>
        <span style="color: #BFBFFF">%L </span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
```

The current contents of the **header CSS** is:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    width: 1000px;
    color: #CFCFCF;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
}

a:link {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: orange;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.snippet{
  background-color: #000000; 
  color: #AFAFDF;
}



.thumbnail {
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   padding: 4px;
   width: auto; /* set width of thumbnail image in 'paragraph' code - not here */
   border:none;
   z-index:0;
   }
.thumbnail:hover {
   border:none;
   background-color: transparent;
   z-index: 50;
   }
.thumbnail span {
   position: absolute;
   left: -9999px;
   visibility: hidden;
   }
.thumbnail span img {
   max-width:256px;  /* set 'large image' max width/height - advise keeping these  */
   max-height:256px; /* the same to avoid inadvertently changing the aspect ratio  */
   width:auto;   /* leave set to auto */
   height:auto;  /* leave set to auto */
   background-color: gray;
   padding: 1px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
.thumbnail:hover span {
   visibility: visible;
   top: 4px;   /* top/left positions 'large image' relative to top left */
   left: 88px; /* of parent thumbnail (plus padding)                    */
   }
</style>
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your HTML code. Try running it through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) first. Also, please share your code as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). I suppose by 'paragraph CSS' you mean 'inline CSS' and by 'header CSS' you mean 'internal CSS'? Try to use inline CSS only when you have no other option. Using internal - or even better - external CSS will make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: Referencing https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/custom.html, I first built upon the example provided by Chris Stark (last example), then added the image popup logic from the example supplied by Paul. The mods were straightforward block shifts, all on items that are bounded by "TD" fields, so I don't see how that has bearing on why some result paragraphs have a width that is not limited to the value specified by the style for the container which is the table itself.  I would expect an internal, auto-assigned scroll-bar to handle any wider "objects".  Use a <p> wrapper to force?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [**discussions**](https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/issues/161) with the developer for **recoll**, it has been determined that the problem was not with the customizations that I was attempting to apply.

The root of the problem was in fact a bug in the recoll code.